# Apache rewrite rule that matches a specific query string

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, query-string

I need to rewrite a specific WordPress URL to a 404 error:

`?page_id=15` to 404

How can I match the query string? Apparently Apache doesn't feed that to the rewrite mod...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `mod_rewrite`, you can match a query string using this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page_id=15
RewriteRule .* - [R=404]
```